# flutter Dynamic icon index in list with for loop

Tags: flutter, icons, key

I would like to create a row of 5 icons with a separate action for each when I use the onPressed event...
I have two ways :

**1 - Hard writing each icons like below --> bad way :-(**

```
    list.add(
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          globalCategoriesIcons[4],
          color: this.categorieSearch[4] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          this.categorieSearch[4] = (this.categorieSearch[4] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
      },)
);
list.add(
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          globalCategoriesIcons[3],
          color: this.categorieSearch[3] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          this.categorieSearch[3] = (this.categorieSearch[3] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
      },)
);
list.add(
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          globalCategoriesIcons[2],
          color: this.categorieSearch[2] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          this.categorieSearch[2] = (this.categorieSearch[2] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
      },)
);
list.add(
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          globalCategoriesIcons[1],
          color: this.categorieSearch[1] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          this.categorieSearch[1] = (this.categorieSearch[1] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
      },)
);
list.add(
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          globalCategoriesIcons[0],
          color: this.categorieSearch[0] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          this.categorieSearch[0] = (this.categorieSearch[0] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
      },)
);
```

**2- Creating a loop --> Smart way :-)**

```
    for(i = 4 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  list.add(
      IconButton(
        key: Key(i.toString()),
        icon: Icon(
            globalCategoriesIcons[i],
            color: this.categorieSearch[i] == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            this.categorieSearch[i] = (this.categorieSearch[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
          });
        },)
  );
}
```

The thing is that my "i" index is badly evaluate to -1 when the event is launched !

In my "Icon color" and in the setState() how can I get the "IconButton key" to assign the action to the good icon ?

Comment: ssee httpss://pastebin.com/thjVrpcr

Comment: of course instead of list of maps (`var categories`) you should use a list of custom classes but i just wanted to make it short and quick

Comment: OK pskink ! I implemented your solution and it works like a charm. I'm not really coomfortable with Dart language so I've not the reflex to use maps ! Thank for your precious help.

Comment: How can I close or mark this subject like solved ? You should earn some points no ? :)

Comment: write a self-answer ;-) - but without those `{"key": value}` maps, use classes: so instead `c["icon"]` use `c.icon`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is to use a List of Objects containing the icon and an enum for the assigned function.

```dart
enum IconFunction { functionOne, functionTwo, ... }

class MyIcons{
  Icon icon;
  IconFunction iconFunc;

  MyIcons({required this.icon, required this.iconFunc});
}
```

You can populate `List<MyIcons>` by adding `MyIcons(icon: ..., iconFunc: ...)` on a List.

For executing the function assigned on the enum, you can pass `MyIcons.iconFunc` from the List and use a switch-case.

```dart
switch (value) {
  case IconFunction.functionOne:
    // Do something
    break;
  case IconFunction.functionTwo:
    // Do something
    break;
}
```